# How not to indent the very first line on a page in LaTeX?

Tags: page-breaking, indentation, paragraphs

If the first line on a page happens to be the first line of a paragraph at the same time, I would like not to indent it (just as if it is the first line of a section). Is there a way to do this automatically? I don't want to use `\noindent` command, because if this line moves elsewhere, I want to indent it.

Thanks ahead for help!

Comment: @Daniel: You may well get a bigger choice of answers over on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Brent: Thanks for link, haven't known this website :).

Comment: That might not be a good idea, as the reader will have no way ot knowing if the text is a continuation from the page before.

Comment: @daleif: That's true, but if the reader reads continuously, he should know that the previous paragraph ended.

Comment: @Daniel: By this argument, you would never need an paragraph indent.

Comment: @Daniel: And how could the reader possibly know if the author _really_ chose a paragraph break?

Comment: In fact, many prefer paragraph indents over vertical space between paragraphs *because* the former also appear at the beginning of the page.

Comment: @Daniel  just imagine that the last paragraph on the preceeding page ended with a dot at the right edge of the textblock. A reader would have no way of knowing if the text on the next page was a continuation of the preceeding page or a new page. Where I work we send some time trying to explain to students that indentation is good for communication

Comment: Ok, ok, I agree with your arguments, will let the indentation there :). Thank a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, I don't think this is a great idea. One problem is that if the previous paragraph ended with a full line, there will be no clue that there is a paragraph break (I suppose you could avoid this by setting `\parfillskip=3em plus1fil` to ensure an unfilled final line).

Anyway, to answer your question, this will be very tricky, because TeX generates paragraphs before it looks at page breaking, so by the time it knows that the first line starts on a new page it is too late to do anything about it. You will need to write something into the aux file at the beginning of each paragraph (using `\everypar`) that you can read back on subsequent runs to determine if this paragraph starts a new page, and if it does, to remove the indent. Unfortunately, the new linebreaks may now change the page breaking and you may need to retex repeatedly, and there is no guarantee that this process will converge.

EDIT: here is the core of a solution, to show that it is possible. It will produce a bunch of errors the first time you compile it, and it doesn't redefine `\everypar` in a way that plays well with other packages, but it shows the basic idea.

EDIT 2: fixed the code up a little (the previous version removed the indent for the first paragraph of the page, no matter if it started on first line of page or not)

```
\documentclass{article}
\raggedbottom % to allow short pages
\addtolength{\topskip}{0pt plus 10pt} % to help allow short pages
\newcounter{parno}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newparb}[2]{\global\@namedef{mypar@b#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\newpare}[2]{\global\@namedef{mypar@e#1}{#2}}
\newpare{0}{0}
\let\oldpar\par
\def\par{\oldpar\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newpare{\theparno}{\thepage}}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\interlinepenalty=1000 % just for example, to encourage paragraphs to start on new pages
\makeatletter
\everypar={%
    \stepcounter{parno}%
    \ifnum \@nameuse{mypar@b\theparno}=\@nameuse{mypar@e\@arabic{\numexpr\value{parno}-1}}%
    \else\setbox0\lastbox\fi
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newparb{\theparno}{\thepage}}%
}
\makeatother
\lipsum[1-60]% dummy text
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would one go about redefining `\everypar` in a way that does play well with other packages?

Answer (score 11):

Right at the begining of the line that you don't want to indent, type:

```
\noindent
```

For example:

```
\section{Introduction}
\noindent
This is the introduction.
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not read that you did not want to use ``noindent`` ;)

Comment: The OP wants _automatic_ detection if the paragraph is at the top of a page. Moreover, after `\section` you usually don't need `\noindent` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

ConTeXt provides a `\beforeeverypagebody` token list that are executed, well, before a page body is constructed. There is also a `\aftereverypagebody` which is executed after the page body is constructed; and `\beforeeveryshipout` and `\aftereveryshipout` that are executed before and after a page is shipped.

To do what you want, you just need to add

```
\appendtoks \noindentation \to \everybeforepagebody
```

For some reason, this does not work on the very first page. However, you can just add a `\noindentation` to get rid of the indent on the first page. Thus, the following gives what you want:

```
\appendtoks \noindentation \to \everybeforepagebody

\setupindenting[big,yes]

\starttext \noindentation

\input knuth 

\page
\input knuth

\stoptext
```

Comment: Does this or a similar function exist for `xelatex`?

Comment: @TilHund: No, but the solution posted by Lev Bishop should work with xeletax as well